# Trap output in exec part of find

Tags: bash

```
myfunc() {

    echo "Hello"

}

export -f myfunc

find / -type f -exec bash -c 'myfunc "$0"' {} \;

var="$(myfunc)"

echo "$var"
```

This will return Hello, I know. But is there a way I can trap `$var` in exec part 
of find?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what means `trap`

Comment: No, there is not. Why do you want to do it anyways?

Comment: I would like to append result of find to global array.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to append result of find to global array.

If you want the result of `find`, you have to put the `find` command between the `$(` `)`.
If you want an array, you have to use extra `(` `)`.

```
var=($(find / -type f -exec bash -c 'myfunc "$0"' {} \;))
```